# Autoplay stops after some time html5 video taken from google drive

Tags: html, google-drive-api, html5-video, autoplay

I have a mp4 video inside html video tag. SRC= is given for the google drive video.
see my code below

```
<video auto play muted loop id="video" class="" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1qSC6ySf6ZZldFRpuBx9EXvDsD-mfve1Z" type="video/mp4">  </video>
```

Note: when I am directly calling mp4 video from my server than it will not pause but when the video is called from google drive it gets paused after few minutes. As I am not showing any controls. I need the video to be played continuously.

the issues I'm getting is
[image]
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/5salman/pen/bGRMyKj

Comment: Seems to keep playing fine when I check, ver after several minutes - maybe a network issue, or specific to a particular browser if you do some more checking?

Comment: Not a network issue because I have tried in different networks this is only happening when I'm using a video from google drive

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherit in Google Drive *(that I can think of)* that would cancel autoplay. More likely you're hitting an `error` event. The video will be loaded via "206 Partial Content" byte-range requests. If it doesn't end up being locally cached then that could make it more susceptible to network issues than on a server that doesn't support byte-range requests. Also consider looking at the network Devtools for any network errors.

Mitigation options:

- **Reduce the size of your video!** It's 14mb for 20 seconds of video. Use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) or something to re-encode the video to a smaller bitrate/size. That will reduce network traffic and make it less likely to choke the viewing device.
- Add an `error` event handler on the `<video>` tag - this can help you with diagnostics, and you can also trigger the video to (try) to play again.

```js
function reloadVideo(vidElement, preserveTime = true) {
  if (preserveTime) {
    // wait to set the current time again until after playable
    const position = vidElement.currentTime;
    var cb = vidElement.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
      if (!isNaN(position) && position < vidElement.duration) {
        // I recommend seeking just a frame or so ahead, just in case there was a decode error on the video
        vidElement.currentTime = position + 1/30;
      }
      vidElement.removeEventListener('canplay', cb);
    });
  }
  
  const src = vidElement.currentSrc;
  vidElement.src = "";
  vidElement.src = src;
  
}

var vidElement = document.querySelector('#video');

// retry on error
var retryErrorCodes = [MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK, MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE];
var SECONDS_BEFORE_RETRY = 5;
vidElement.addEventListener('error', evt => {
  if (retryErrorCodes.includes(vidElement.error.code)) {
    setTimeout(reloadVideo, SECONDS_BEFORE_RETRY * 1000, vidElement);
  }
}
```

- **(Not Recommended)** if you *need* it to keep running you can add a `setInterval` function that restarts the video if it's paused. Keep in mind that these "zombie" functions can get annoying if you don't manage them carefully.

```js
// use setInterval to keep retrying the playback
var SECONDS_BETWEEN_PLAYING_CHECKS = 10;
var keepPlayingTimer = setInterval(function () {
  var vidElement = document.querySelector('#video');

  // make sure the element is still there
  if (vidElement && typeof vidElement.play === 'function') {
    // if it's not playing start it playing again
    if (vidElement.paused) {
      vidElement.play();
    }
  } else {
    // don't call this function again if video element is gone
    clearInterval(keepPlayingTimer);
  }
}, SECONDS_BETWEEN_PLAYING_CHECKS * 1000);
```

Comment: I used these codes but the problem is still there.  `if (vidElement.paused)` is not called when the video is paused. The problem I think is the cookies attribute not from same site. because the cookies are blocked.  I'm going to attach an image in the question. Please suggest some solution

Comment: that's a different issue, and unlikely the cause. You can add a `pause` event listener to the `<video>` element to see if it's getting paused, or add additional logging on error events, but provided information isn't enough to determine cause

Comment: before I don't have any errors but once the video is stopped I get 403 Error =`GET https://doc-0g-30-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/ka19vg7c5oel814tqdttevsop2h9b7a9/1632374325000/14107644755917828581/*/1qSC6ySf6ZZldFRpuBx9EXvDsD-mfve1Z?e=download 403` and `.play()` or `.pause` don't get called